# How to add TreeView nodes dynamically as a child of already created nodes

Tags: asp.net, treeview, nodes

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 project, I have a TreeView, that takes data from database (PostgreSQL). This is how do I see in my page:

[image]

```
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

Question is how to get them under the "Executor" node? How to add them as a child of "Executor" node

Here is the markup:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
    <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Executor" Value="Executor">
            <asp:TreeNode Text="ShowAll" Value="showAll"></asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

And code behind:

```
private void GetTreeViewItems()
{
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PGcon"].ConnectionString;
        NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr);
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT username FROM users", conCon); 
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        daDa.Fill(ds);      

        foreach (DataRow level1DataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            TreeNode parentTreeNode = new TreeNode();
            parentTreeNode.Text = level1DataRow["username"].ToString();          
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(parentTreeNode);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem!

```
TreeNode a1 = new TreeNode("Apple");
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(a1);
        foreach (DataRow level1DataRow in dsDs.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            TreeNode parentTreeNode = new TreeNode();
            parentTreeNode.Text = level1DataRow["username"].ToString();
            //TreeView1.Nodes.Add(parentTreeNode);


            a1.ChildNodes.Add(parentTreeNode);

        }
```